# Show that there is an odd number of binomial coefficients when n is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

> Let $n>1$ be an odd integer.
>
> Show that there is an odd number of odd numbers in the sequence:
> $\binom{n}{1}, \binom{n}{2}, \binom{n}{3}, ..., \binom{n}{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

I've tried doing it by separating the problem into two cases, one in which $n=4k+1$ and one in which $n=4k+3$  where $k$ is a full number. Then by supposing that $\binom{n}{i}$ is either even or odd for a given $i$, then by writing $\binom{n}{i+1}$ as $\frac{\binom{n}{i}}{i+1} (n-i)$ in order to determine the parity of $\binom{n}{i+1}$. I didn't get anywhere.

Could someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, n>1. Lemme fix that.

Comment: Ignoring $n=1$, show that $\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} \binom nk$ is an odd sum. If the contrary that there are even number of odd terms (plus any number of even terms), the sum would be even.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring $n=1$, the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} \binom nk$ is an odd sum:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom nk &= 2^n\\
\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2} \binom nk &= 2^{n-1}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} \binom nk &= 2^{n-1} -1\\
&\equiv 1\pmod2
\end{align*}$$

If the contrary that there are even number of odd terms (plus any number of even terms), the sum would be even:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} \binom nk
&\equiv \left(\text{# of odd terms}\right)\cdot 1 + \left(\text{# of even terms}\right)\cdot 0 &&\pmod 2\\
\left(\text{# of odd terms}\right) &\equiv  1 &&\pmod2
\end{align*}$$